How to find the first duplicate number in an array in C#?
I'm learning C# and trying to solve a problem where I need to find the first duplicate number in an array. For example, if the array is { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5 }, the answer should be 2 because it's the first number that appears more than once.
Here's my current approach:
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5 };
int duplicate = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
        {
            duplicate = numbers[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (duplicate != -1) break;
}

Console.WriteLine(duplicate);

This works, but it feels slow. Is there a better way to solve this problem, especially for larger arrays? I heard about using HashSet, but I’m not sure how to implement it.

What output do you expect for the input of {1, 2, 2, 1}?

You use the HashSet class, not implement it.
var hashset = new HashSet<int>();

and you can check with
if(!hashset.Add(numbers[i])) then return numbers[i];

Such that your code can achieve time in O(n) instead of O(n^2) by nested loop.
I will leave the rest for you to do your work.

It's O(nlogn), not O(n). It's the same as sorting the input array and finding the first number that repeats itself in the adjacent index (just much more inefficient).

@Blindy complexity of the hashset aproach Is O(n) in worst case. You dont need the inner loop then.

That will fail on {1,2,2,1} as it will return 2 instead of 1

@SirRufo What makes you think that is the wrong result?

@mjwills It is not me, but computer says no

I suspect that is more "the OP's original code is bad", but I've asked them to clarify.

@TimSchmelter, the worst case complexity of adding to a hashset is O(n) (to handle collisions), and so the worst case complexity of adding n numbers is O(n^2). Collisions aside, the expected complexity is O(nlogn), as I explained. Take out a pen and paper and write it out if you need to understand it.

@Blindy: If a HashSet<T> must be resized(the internal array), HashSet<T>.Add has O(n) complexity, but normally it's an O(1) operation. That's even documented. So you could initialize it with numbers.Length to avoid resizing. Then the whole loop is O(n) in worst case, where n equals numbers.Length.

@Blindy: Since when others are insulted on SO? I don't care if you are more educated(i have also 25 years of experiance as sw-engineer). So you say that microsoft's documentation is wrong or you didnt even read my comment and the provided link?
